How to reference an React.Component's Function from a Jest Mock
I have the following (example) component that I am attempting to mock as part of an integration test.
interface MyComponentProps { acceptableRoles: string[]}

export default class MyComponent extends Component<React.PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>> {

    public canRender(currentRoles: string[]): boolean {
        // determine if any current roles intersect with acceptableRoles
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {(roles) => this.canRender(roles)
                    ? this.props.children
                    : null
                }
            </MyContext.Consumer>
    }
}

I want to mock the output of render() to remove the <MyContext.Consumer> wrapper and passing in the roles into my mock.
When used in the component I'm testing, the above component is simply
<MyComponent acceptableRoles={"role1", "role2"}>
    <div>Show this if allowed</div>
</MyComponent> 

I have tried a number of things and this feels like the closest I can get; however, I receive an error saying that origin.canRender is not a function.  When I check it, it is undefined.
const myTestRoles = ["role3", "role4"]; //changes within different tests

jest.mock("./MyComponent", () => (props: any) => {
  const origin = jest.requireActual<MyComponent>("./MyComponent");
  // console.info("Origin: " + origin.canRender); //Outputs as "Origin: undefined"

  return <div>{
            origin.canRender(_user)
            ? props.children
            : null}
          </div>;
  });

Everything "works" until I add a call to the `origin.canRender' which provides the "not a function" error.
I know strict unit testing I would just skip this call with an explicit mock but this got me really wondering if this can be done.
Is it possible to call such an instance method from a mocked method?

Since you are using export default MyComponent, the jest.requireActual('./MyComponent') statement will return { default: [class MyComponent extends Component] }.
You can access the public method of a JavaScript class by its .prototype property.
e.g.
MyComponent.tsx:
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext<string[]>([]);

interface MyComponentProps {
  acceptableRoles: string[];
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component<React.PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>> {
  public canRender(currentRoles: string[]): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  public render() {
    return <MyContext.Consumer>{(roles) => (this.canRender(roles) ? this.props.children : null)}</MyContext.Consumer>;
  }
}

index.test.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

jest.mock('./MyComponent', () => (props: any) => {
  const origin = jest.requireActual('./MyComponent');
  console.log(" ~ jest.mock ~ origin:", origin)
  console.info('Origin: ', origin.default.prototype.canRender);

  return <div>{origin.default.prototype.canRender(['role3']) ? props.children : null}</div>;
});

describe('78269182', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    render(
      <MyComponent acceptableRoles={['role1', 'role2']}>
        <div>Show this if allowed</div>
      </MyComponent>,
    );
    screen.debug();
  });
});

Test result:
  console.log
     ~ jest.mock ~ origin: { default: [class MyComponent extends Component] }

      at log (stackoverflow/78269182/index.test.tsx:7:11)

  console.info
    Origin:  [Function: canRender]

      at info (stackoverflow/78269182/index.test.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            Show this if allowed
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:87:13)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78269182/index.test.tsx
  78269182
    √ should pass (40 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.086 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

package versions:
"jest": "^29.7.0"


This definitely gets me further than where I was. Thanks!  However, in your example, MyComponent module's canRender() function doesn't reference its props.  Since React.Component<>.props is read-only - how would I be able to update that after calling jest.requireActual()?
